# Undefined behavior of printf in C?

Tags: c, stdio

What should be the output of a single percent sign?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    printf("%");
}
```

"Unknown format code" is not like "Unknown escape sequence".

Comment: It doesn't make much sense anyway. What do you think it should print?

Comment: The answer is in your title.  UB

Comment: Does it matter what it prints?

Comment: 7.19.6.1.4 says that a `%` must be followed by a conversion specifier, and later (7.19.6.1.9) if the conversion specification is not valid then it's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're doing is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Section 7.21.6.1p9 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding format specifiers for `fprintf` (and by extension `printf`) states:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.  If any argument is
> not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
> undefined.

Also, gcc will generate a warning with `-Wall` if you do this:

```
warning: spurious trailing ‘%’ in format [-Wformat=]
```

The correct way to print a `%` character is with the format specifier `%%`.

```
printf("%%");
```

Comment: May be worth noting that with warnings turned on, a warning should be received about `printf("%");`

Answer (score -1):

`%` is used to signal that you want to print a variable e.g.

```
int i = 10;
printf("%d", i); //prints 10
```

In order to just print the '%' sign you must escape it as

`printf("%%");`

Comment: While everything in this answer is perfectly correct, except the escaping of the `%` which should be `%%` instead of `\%`, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: My mistake. Would advise editing the answer instead of leaving a comment in the future @Jabberwocky

Comment: @MatthewKerian You mean Jabberwocky should have edited the answer to answer the question? That part of the process is definitely your job. :-)

Comment: @IanAbbott No sense in leaving up a wrong answer for a mistake like that.